# dynamic binding of rows and columns to a grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, observablecollection

With a DataGrid object in WPF, we can bind its rows to an observable collection such that as rows are added or removed to/from the collection, the UI updates to display the changes.  I am looking to do something similar with a Grid control as part of a User Control I am trying to create.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind a collection to some sort of self updating UI in my experience an ItemsControl with custom ItemPanel and a ItemContainerStyle with a Template set as well as ItemTemplates for different kinds of objects in the collection is quite powerfulI.
It all depends on your exect scenario though. If you can elaborate i could whip up some XAML.

Comment: yeah I discovered some stuff that would suggest that is the best approach... I need to digest what this means, if I have any problems I'll definitely follow up.